# Convergence of partial sums of an alternating series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose $x_0, x_1, x_2,\ldots$ is a sequence of positive numbers monotonically converging to zero. Then $x_o - x_1 + x_2 -x_3+\cdots$ converges.

How would you prove this statement? I know you would have to either prove that the sequence of partial sums has an upper bound or consider $n, m > N$ and consider the series between $x_n$ and $x_m$ and prove it is less than any real epsilon, but not exactly sure how to carry the proof rigorously out.

Comment: "consider n, m > N and consider the series between n and m and prove it is less than any real epsilon" I'm sorry, but this reads like gibberish.

Comment: "the sequence of partial sums has an upper bound". This does not imply convergence, since the terms of your series are not positive.

Comment: There is a proof (or at least proof sketch) on the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series).

Comment: What is $N$? For no $n,m$, is "the series between $x_n$ and $x_m$" less than any real epsilon.